# The DLL manifest is missing

Tags: reactjs, react-boilerplate

I must do some changes on a project, the problem is that when I try to run it using `npm start` every time I get error.
The error is:

> The DLL manifest is missing. please run `npm run build:dll`

When I run `npm run build:dll`  I get

> Building the webpack DLL ...
>
> ERROR in ./~/react-router-scroll/lib/StateStorage.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'history/lib/DOMStateStorage' in 'C:\project\node_modules\react-router-scroll\lib'
>
> @ ./~/react-router-scroll/lib/StateStorage.js 5:23-61
>
> @ ./~/react-router-scroll/lib/ScrollBehaviorContext.js
>
> @ ./~/react-router-scroll/lib/useScroll.js
>
> @ ./~/react-router-scroll/lib/index.js
>
> @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps
>
> ERROR in ./~/cpx/~/chokidar/~/is-binary-path/index.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'json-loader' in 'C:\project'
>
> @ ./~/cpx/~/chokidar/~/is-binary-path/index.js 3:23-51
>
> @ ./~/cpx/~/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js
>
> @ ./~/cpx/~/chokidar/index.js
>
> @ ./~/cpx/lib/cpx.js
>
> @ ./~/cpx/lib/index.js
>
> @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

Answer (score 0):

had this same error, but after running `npm install` everything works

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30533468)